# Developer tools - How to inspect the elements which are added momentarily (by JQuery)?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, slider, developer-tools, firefox-developer-tools

I am looking at how a website is designed using the **Inspector** in Chrome. I can also use Firefox Developer tools or Firefox Web Developer add-on or Chrome Web Developer extension.

So this website has a **slide-show** and they are **using JQuery** for it. As I am looking at the markup and CSS in the inspector, **I see two things constantly** changing as the slides change:

1. One is **`opacity`** CSS property which is understandable, but I'd like
   to see the changing values, but it changes too fast to see read
   anything.
2. Second- **a `div` is added** in another `div` as the slides change **momentarily**, but the moment when it appears is too short to notice anything except that it is a `div`.

So the question is that

1. **Is there a way to stop the slideshow** so that I can temporarily get rid of that blinking sort of effect (by speedy adding and removal and changing of elements and values)?
2. **Where can I inspect the `div` element which gets added for such a short moment**, and then gets removed? And where can I see what changes in the value of `opacity` takes place?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a link to an example of what you are trying to inspect. Generally speaking, Firefox devtool's inspector has a feature that allows you to look at the event handlers for jQuery events, see [this post](http://flailingmonkey.com/view-jquery-and-jquery-live-events-in-firefox-devtools/) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop the slideshow so that I can temporarily get rid of that blinking sort of effect (by speedy adding and removal and changing of elements and values)?

If the opacity is animated with a CSS transition or animation, you can use the newly added animation inspection tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Work_with_animations) and [Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2015/01/chrome-41-beta-new-es6-features-and.html) which let you pause animations, or even slow them down.

If however the opacity is animated via javascript, by rapidly increasing/decreasing the `element.style.opacity` value, then you can use the debugger's ability to **break on dom mutations**. [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints-mutation-events) can do that, however it's [not yet implemented in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1004678).

> Where can I inspect the div element which gets added for such a short moment, and then gets removed? And where can I see what changes in the value of opacity takes place?

Same answer here, you should use the debugger's break on dom mutation feature to halt the debugger when that `div` gets inserted. This will let you see exactly which line of javascript code inserts/removes the `div` or modifies the `opacity`, and will let you inspect the elements at that point in time.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm getting your question straight, you want to "study" a slideshow in order to understand how it works.

Have you tried to view the source and search it for the piece of jQuery code you want to inspect?
If the source code of that page has not been compressed you should be able to understand what is writen there.